# Overloading + operator for arrays in groovy

Tags: groovy, overloading, operator-keyword

I am a groovy newbie. Maybe this is a piece of cake, but I want to overload the + operator for arrays/lists to code like this

```
def a= [1,1,1]
def b= [2,2,2]

assert [3,3,3] == a + b
```

Comment: How I overload the + operator for lists?

Answer (score 7):

I wouldn't recommend globally overriding well-established behaviors. But, if you insist, this will do as you ask:

```
ArrayList.metaClass.plus << {Collection b -> 
    [delegate, b].transpose().collect{x, y -> x+y}
}
```

A more localized alternative would be to use a category:

```
class PlusCategory{
    public static Collection plus(Collection a, Collection b){
        [a, b].transpose().collect{x, y -> x+y}
    }
}
use (PlusCategory){
    assert [3, 3, 3] == [1, 1, 1] + [2, 2, 2]
}
```

However, I would probably create a generic zipWith method (as in functional programming), allowing one to easily specify different behaviors...

```
Collection.metaClass.zipWith = {Collection b, Closure c -> 
    [delegate, b].transpose().collect(c)
}
assert [3, 3, 3] == [1, 1, 1].zipWith([2, 2, 2]){a, b -> a+b}
assert [2, 2, 2] == [1, 1, 1].zipWith([2, 2, 2]){a, b -> a*b}
```

Comment: Or `[[1, 1, 1],[2, 2, 2]].transpose().collect { it.sum() }`

Comment: @tim_yates - Nice, I hadn't considered using sum there. I guess if one wanted to be truly decadent it could be abbreviated to: [[1, 1, 1],[2, 2, 2]].transpose()*.sum()

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm trying to do the same thing with "-" operator. I added the minus method to the Category class, but it is not working. It seems that groovy is not understanding that the minus is the - operator. Nothing is happening. Again, thanks for the help!

Comment: @JulioCM - Try changing either (or both) the a or b parameters in your minus method from 'Collection' to 'List.' There's some arcane reason why this works, but I can't tell you what that reason is, exactly.