# Sum the content of 2 list in Groovy

Tags: groovy, arraylist, sum

I have two lists in Groovy and need to sum the contents of both.

For example:

```
list1 = [1,1,1]
list2 = [1,1,1]
```

I expected this result:

```
total = [2,2,2]
```

---

I try to sum with + operator o .sum method, but I have a concatenation of the lists.

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

It's Groovy enough groovy or I need to loop each element of the lists?

Comment: Possible repeat of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443557/overloading-operator-for-arrays-in-groovy

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Groovy's [`List.transpose()`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#transpose()) works like `zip` in some other languages.  Try this:

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [4,5,6]
assert [list1, list2].transpose()*.sum() == [5,7,9]
```

Comment: that's the nicest answer so far (sorry no upvotes left for today). What's the star?

Comment: It's the [spread operator](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Operators?showChildren=false#Operators-SpreadOperator%28.%29), shorthand for `collect` over the list.

Comment: With this amazing answer, I remembered a question I asked earlier: [Clarity vs Obfuscation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433137/clarity-vs-obfuscation-writing-code)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of a built-in solution, but here's a workaround using `collect` and the Java `Queue`'s `poll()` method:

```
def list1 = [1, 2, 3]
def list2 = [4, 5, 6] as Queue

assert [5, 7, 9] == list1.collect { it + list2.poll() }
```

Answer (score 2):

In most functional programming languages, this is done by using a `map2` (ocaml) or `zipWith` (haskell) function, with for example:

```
let total = List.map2 (+) list1 list2;;
```

I didn't find any equivalent in the groovy documentation, but apparently, you can easily define `zipWith` (found at http://cs.calstatela.edu/wiki/index.php/Courses/CS_537/Summer_2008/Chapter_4._Collective_Groovy_datatypes):

```
zipWith = {f, a, b -> 
 result = []
 0.upto(Math.min(a.size(), b.size())-1){index -> result << f(a[index], b[index])}
 result}

assert zipWith({x, y -> x + y}, [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7]) ==  [5, 7, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

Prototype (JavaScript framework) has a [method `zip()`](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/enumerable/zip) that does exactly what you need. That doesn't help you though, I know. Funny, I would have expected Groovy to have something similar, but I could not find anything in either the [`Collection`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html) or [`List`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html) class.

Anyway, here is a not-too-pretty implementation of `zip()`:

```
List.metaClass.zip = { List other, Closure cl ->
    List result = [];
    Iterator left = delegate.iterator();
    Iterator right = other.iterator();
    while(left.hasNext()&& right.hasNext()){
        result.add(
            cl.call(left.next(), right.next())
        );
    }
    result;
}
```

And here it is in action:

```
def list1 = [1, 1, 1]
def list2 = [1, 1, 1]

print (list1.zip(list2) {it1, it2 -> it1 + it2})
```

Output:

> [2, 2, 2]

---

Of course you can also do it in a less generic way if you want to solve exactly your problem (and not implement a generic zip/map function) :

```
List.metaClass.addValues = { List other ->
    List result = [];
    Iterator left = delegate.iterator();
    Iterator right = other.iterator();
    while(left.hasNext()&& right.hasNext()){
        result.add(
            left.next() + right.next()
        );
    }
    result;
}

def list1 = [1, 1, 1]
def list2 = [1, 1, 1]

print (list1.addValues(list2))
// Output again: [2, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you find the .*sum() solution above a tad confusing to read (very nice though) you can also do this:

```
l1=[1,2,3]
l2=[4,5,6]

println([l1,l2].transpose().collect{it[0]+it[1]})
```

Of course it allows for more complex calculations than just summing.