# Is there any analog for Scala 'zip' function in Groovy?

Tags: scala, groovy

In Scala I can write something like this:

```
val a = List(1, 2, 3)
val b = List(4, 5)
println(a zip b)
```

That would produce `List((1,4), (2,5))` as output.
Now I have two collections in Groovy and want to zip them in similar fashion. What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: Check out the transpose method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584393/sum-the-content-of-2-list-in-groovy

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Groovy's equivalent of Scala's `zip` is [`List#transpose`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#transpose%28%29), which can be called on a list of lists:

```
assert [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]].transpose() == [[1, 4], [2, 5]]
```

Comment: Note that Scala also has transpose, but requires the lists to be the same size, while Groovy truncates (like `zip` does).

Comment: I'm not sure why the Groovy guys decided to rename all of these well-known functional primitives.

Comment: @AndresJaanTack Groovy actually took all these function names from Ruby.

Comment: It's a bit curious then, since [Ruby actually has zip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-zip) ... also I looked it up, and Ruby's `filter` is called `select`, while Groovy's `findAll`... and neither Ruby has `findAll` nor Groovy has `select`

Comment: Then again, Ruby took its names from SmallTalk... and SmallTalk has `select` but no `findAll` just like Ruby, so it seems like it's Groovy that's out of line (otoh SmallTalk like Groovy doesn't have `zip`)

Comment: `transpose()` returns a List of Lists. To get a Map: `transpose().collectEntries()`