# Groovy zipping lists or flattening by level

Tags: list, groovy, flatten

I am trying to zip two lists. I found a solution using `transpose` (from this link: [Is there any analog for Scala 'zip' function in Groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13879489/is-there-any-analog-for-scala-zip-function-in-groovy)) but the result is not quite what I expected. I want to have lists zipped! I really mean zipped.

Given:

```
a = [ [1,2,3] , [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ]
b = [ ['a','b','c'] , ['d','e','f'], ['g','h','j']]
```

Expected result:

```
zipped = [ [1,2,3], 
           ['a','b','c'], 
           [4,5,6], 
           ['d','e','f'], (...) ]
```

But transpose gives me:

```
[a,b].transpose() = [ [[1,2,3],['a','b','c']]
                      [[4,5,6],['d','e','f']]
                      [[7,8,9],['g','h','j']] ]
```

I tried to somehow flatten the last list but there is no flattenning by level. Every single list is being flatten where I want just to get out of the "rows" lists,

Comment: Just for the record. I have written a method to make something like this on my own but I'd rather use something that already exists than reinventing the wheel ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
[a, b].transpose().collectMany { it }
```

Answer (score 1):

[`flatten()`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#flatten%28%29) should be a good candidate to work here, but it is recursive, and ends up flattening the last level of the tree. I'd like to suggest a variation using `inject`:

```
def zip(a,b) {
    [a,b].transpose().inject([]) { result, list -> result + list }
}

def a = [ [1,2,3] , [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ]
def b = [ ['a','b','c'] , ['d','e','f'], ['g','h','j']]

assert zip(a,b) == [
    [1, 2, 3], 
    ['a', 'b', 'c'], 
    [4, 5, 6], 
    ['d', 'e', 'f'], 
    [7, 8, 9], 
    ['g', 'h', 'j']
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas came to my head:

```
def a = [ [1,2,3] , [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ]
def b = [ ['a','b','c'] , ['d','e','f'], ['g','h','j']]

def l = []
[a,b].transpose().collect { it.collect { l << it} }
assert l ==  [[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c'], [4, 5, 6], ['d', 'e', 'f'], [7, 8, 9], ['g', 'h', 'j']]


def k = [a,b].transpose().inject([]) {acc, val -> 
    val.collect {acc << it }
    acc
}
assert k ==  [[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c'], [4, 5, 6], ['d', 'e', 'f'], [7, 8, 9], ['g', 'h', 'j']]
```