# Create a single collection from multiple collections in a way that maximises distance between elements of the same initial collection

Tags: algorithm, scala

Suppose you have the following data structure:

```
val words   = Seq("cat", "dog", "kid", "dee", "ding", "chip", "chord")
val grouped = words.groupBy(_.charAt(0))
```

What's a good functional way of creating another collection that's formed by taking each element of the sequences in `grouped` in round robin? I.e. something like this:

`Seq("kid", "dog", "cat", "dee", "chip", "ding", "chord")`

or

`Seq("dog", "cat", "kid", "dee", "chip", "ding", "chord")`

We do not know in advance how many sequences will be in `grouped`.

Comment: I am not familiar with Scala, but I found this similar question: [Groovy zipping lists or flattening by level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24692690/groovy-zipping-lists-or-flattening-by-level). It suggests using `[a, b].transpose().collectMany { it }` on your list of groups; or alternatively, `.transpose().inject([]) { result, list -> result + list }`

Comment: `grouped` is a `Map[Char, Seq[String]]` so I don't understand what is the logic you want, like you just want to pick one element for each group?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez it seems that OP needs to flatten the map values taking elements by one from each key and  not "sequentially" as `grouped.values.flatten` will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can flatten values using `zipWithIndex` to combine them with index inside every group then group by that index and flatten again:

```scala
grouped.values
    .flatMap(xs => xs.zipWithIndex)
    .groupBy(_._2)
    .values
    .flatMap(_.unzip._1)
```