# elementary operator overloading in Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, operator-overloading, metaclass

I am new in Groovy and I have done only C# and C++ before, so I have some problems with getting used to Java and especially to Groovy that we use for our project. So the question concerns Groovy.

I am trying to:

- create a new class X:

```groovy
class X {
        double val
}
```

- Overload elementary operators (+,-,*,/,** etc) for variables of class X

The problem is:
- In Groovy I can overload operators for class X including one attribute - value (that is double)

```
X plus(X obj){
  X newobj = new X(this.val + obj.val)
  return newobj
}
```

and

```
X plus(double obj){
  X newobj = new X(this.val + obj)
  return newobj
}
```

But how do I do if the double object is on the first place (left hand side) in addition? Like:

`double a
X b
X result = a + b
// it will not work because operator + of a is not overloaded to provide addition of b`

Do I need to overload something like this but for double operators?:

```
ArrayList.metaClass.plus << {Collection b -> 
    [delegate, b].transpose().collect{x, y -> x+y}
}
```

as was said in 
[Overloading + operator for arrays in groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443557/overloading-operator-for-arrays-in-groovy)

Maybe there is a way to add a method as closure accessing metaclass?

Unfortunately the example with arrays is the closest answer that I have found in the internet. Hope there is a way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can just redefine it for Double: `Double.metaClass.plus = {...}`

Beware! in groovy

```
def d0 = 2.1
println d0.getClass() //  java.math.BigDecimal

double d1 = 2.1
println d1.getClass() //  java.lang.Double
```

Comment: Thanks it works! The problem I was not aware of is some language limitations. We work not on pure Groovy but the one developed for GPU programming, so I can run it in groovy but the tests do not work on GPU. So I have neded up defining dumb functions instead of overloading:)